# add module snd-aloop

Tags: server, kernel, alsa

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                0
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2131.964
BogoMIPS:              5199.99
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     VMware
Virtualization type:   full
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc eagerfpu cpuid_faultin
g pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust smep arat spec_ctrl intel_stibp arch_capabiliti
es
```

```
lsb_release -a 

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:Ubuntu
Description:Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:16.04
Codename:xenial

apt show linux-generic

Package: linux-generic
Version: 4.4.0.190.196
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Source: linux-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 16.4 kB
Depends: linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.190.196), linux-headers-generic (= 4.4.0.190.196)
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 1788 B
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

```
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-118-generic         4.15.0-118.119~16.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1003-gke             4.4.0-1003.3                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1005-gke             4.4.0-1005.6                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1006-gke             4.4.0-1006.6                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1008-gke             4.4.0-1008.8                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1009-gke             4.4.0-1009.9                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic          4.4.0-101.124                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1010-gke             4.4.0-1010.10                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1012-gke             4.4.0-1012.12                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1013-gke             4.4.0-1013.13                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1014-gke             4.4.0-1014.14                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1016-gke             4.4.0-1016.16                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1018-gke             4.4.0-1018.18                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1022-gke             4.4.0-1022.22                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1024-gke             4.4.0-1024.24                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1026-gke             4.4.0-1026.26                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1027-gke             4.4.0-1027.27                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1028-gke             4.4.0-1028.28                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic          4.4.0-103.126                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1031-gke             4.4.0-1031.31                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1032-gke             4.4.0-1032.32                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1033-gke             4.4.0-1033.33                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-1034-gke             4.4.0-1034.34                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic          4.4.0-104.127                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic          4.4.0-108.131                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic          4.4.0-109.132                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic          4.4.0-112.135                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic          4.4.0-116.140                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic          4.4.0-119.143                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic          4.4.0-121.145                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic          4.4.0-122.146                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic          4.4.0-124.148                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic          4.4.0-127.153                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic          4.4.0-128.154                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic          4.4.0-130.156                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-131-generic          4.4.0-131.157                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic          4.4.0-133.159                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic          4.4.0-134.160                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic          4.4.0-135.161                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic          4.4.0-137.163                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic          4.4.0-138.164                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

ii  linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic          4.4.0-138.164                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic          4.4.0-139.165                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-140-generic          4.4.0-140.166                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic          4.4.0-141.167                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic          4.4.0-142.168                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-187-generic          4.4.0-187.217                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic          4.4.0-190.220                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic           4.4.0-21.37                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic           4.4.0-22.40                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic           4.4.0-24.43                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic           4.4.0-28.47                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic           4.4.0-31.50                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic           4.4.0-34.53                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic           4.4.0-36.55                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic           4.4.0-38.57                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic           4.4.0-42.62                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic           4.4.0-43.63                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic           4.4.0-45.66                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic           4.4.0-47.68                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic           4.4.0-51.72                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic           4.4.0-53.74                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic           4.4.0-57.78                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic           4.4.0-59.80                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic           4.4.0-62.83                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic           4.4.0-63.84                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic           4.4.0-64.85                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic           4.4.0-66.87                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-67-generic           4.4.0-67.88                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic           4.4.0-70.91                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic           4.4.0-71.92                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic           4.4.0-72.93                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic           4.4.0-75.96                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic           4.4.0-77.98                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic           4.4.0-78.99                                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic           4.4.0-79.100                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic           4.4.0-81.104                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic           4.4.0-83.106                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic           4.4.0-87.110                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic           4.4.0-89.112                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9019-euclid          4.4.0-9019.20                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9020-euclid          4.4.0-9020.21                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9021-euclid          4.4.0-9021.22                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9022-euclid          4.4.0-9022.23                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9023-euclid          4.4.0-9023.24                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9025-euclid          4.4.0-9025.27                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9026-euclid          4.4.0-9026.28                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9027-euclid          4.4.0-9027.29                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9028-euclid          4.4.0-9028.30                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-9029-euclid          4.4.0-9029.31                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic           4.4.0-91.114                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic           4.4.0-92.115                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic           4.4.0-93.116                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic           4.4.0-96.119                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic           4.4.0-97.120                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic           4.4.0-98.121                                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1003-gke       4.4.0-1003.3                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1005-gke       4.4.0-1005.6                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1006-gke       4.4.0-1006.6                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1008-gke       4.4.0-1008.8                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1009-gke       4.4.0-1009.9                                    amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic    4.4.0-101.124                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1010-gke       4.4.0-1010.10                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1012-gke       4.4.0-1012.12                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1013-gke       4.4.0-1013.13                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1014-gke       4.4.0-1014.14                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1016-gke       4.4.0-1016.16                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1018-gke       4.4.0-1018.18                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1022-gke       4.4.0-1022.22                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1024-gke       4.4.0-1024.24                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1026-gke       4.4.0-1026.26                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1027-gke       4.4.0-1027.27                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1028-gke       4.4.0-1028.28                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic    4.4.0-103.126                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1031-gke       4.4.0-1031.31                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1032-gke       4.4.0-1032.32                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1033-gke       4.4.0-1033.33                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-1034-gke       4.4.0-1034.34                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-104-generic    4.4.0-104.127                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-108-generic    4.4.0-108.131                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic    4.4.0-109.132                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic    4.4.0-112.135                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic    4.4.0-116.140                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic    4.4.0-119.143                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-121-generic    4.4.0-121.145                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-122-generic    4.4.0-122.146                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic    4.4.0-124.148                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic    4.4.0-127.153                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-128-generic    4.4.0-128.154                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-130-generic    4.4.0-130.156                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-131-generic    4.4.0-131.157                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-133-generic    4.4.0-133.159                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic    4.4.0-134.160                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-135-generic    4.4.0-135.161                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic    4.4.0-137.163                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic    4.4.0-138.164                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic    4.4.0-139.165                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-140-generic    4.4.0-140.166                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic    4.4.0-141.167                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-142-generic    4.4.0-142.168                                   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic     4.4.0-21.37                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic     4.4.0-22.40                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic     4.4.0-24.43                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic     4.4.0-28.47                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic     4.4.0-31.50                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic     4.4.0-34.53                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic     4.4.0-36.55                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic     4.4.0-38.57                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic     4.4.0-42.62                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic     4.4.0-43.63                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic     4.4.0-45.66                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic     4.4.0-47.68                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic     4.4.0-51.72                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic     4.4.0-53.74                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic     4.4.0-57.78                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic     4.4.0-59.80                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic     4.4.0-62.83                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic     4.4.0-63.84                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic     4.4.0-64.85                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic     4.4.0-66.87                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-67-generic     4.4.0-67.88                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic     4.4.0-70.91                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic     4.4.0-71.92                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic     4.4.0-72.93                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic     4.4.0-75.96                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic     4.4.0-77.98                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic     4.4.0-78.99                                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

first I install linux-image-extra-virtual

```
apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

change the grub

```
  GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2"
  GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
  GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
  #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

then reboot

```
echo "snd-aloop" >> /etc/modules
```

when I enter below command I got the error

```
modprobe snd-aloop
```

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.4.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0
```

could you help me solve this problem

Comment: What are your CPU architecture and hardware?

Comment: @N0rbert i edited post with cpu architecute

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to the question body.

Comment: Thank you@N0rbert i updated

Comment: I can't understand some moments - are you using real hardware of VM somewhere? Why do you have GKE kernels? What is your currently running kernel? Please remove old kernels by `sudo apt-get install byobu` followed by `sudo purge-old-kernels`. Then reboot and add output of `uname -a` to the question.

Comment: I am using vm @N0rbert

Comment: @N0rbert this is saas provider https://flow.ch/appengine/

Answer (score 0):

This module [is included](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=snd-aloop) into the default kernel.

So I would recommend to simply install the default kernel by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

with its *-extra* part by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

and reboot.

Comment: I Installed it is not working the same error happens. I think the kernel is not switching.